# Referencing figures with numbers in Sphinx and reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext, python-sphinx

When writing RST that will be processed with [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/index.html), I can't get Sphinx LaTeX output to use figure numbers when referencing figures. For instance, this code:

```
The lemmings are attacking, as can be seen in :ref:`figlem`.

.. _figlem:

.. figure:: _static/lemming_invasion.* 

   They're coming!
```

Will be converted into this:

> The lemmings are attacking, as can be
>   seen in *They're coming!*
>
> /image goes here/
>
> Figure 1.1: They're coming!

But what I want is the "standard" LaTeX way of referencing figures, like this:

> The lemmings are attacking, as can be
>   seen in Figure 1.1

How do I achieve this? The code I'm currently using is what the Sphinx manual recommends, but it doesn't produce the output I want.

Comment: Looks like an important feature to request.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I really need this feature.

Comment: @jterrace Nope, never found the solution.

Comment: @Lucas found a module that does it in my answer

Comment: @jterrace Sadly, that module did not exist when I was trying to solve this problem. Still, thanks for finding it and posting the answer; hopefully it will help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [numfig](https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig/overview) extension does exactly this. I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me initially (for HTML), but I used the fix by 'rrieber' here: https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig/issue/6/notimplementederror-unknown-node-num_ref
and was able to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: How did you get it to work? The diff file provided by rrieber doesn't match the numfig.py I grabbed from that bitbucket repository.

Comment: Try the version I updated here: https://github.com/jterrace/sphinxtr/blob/master/extensions/numfig.py (remove references to figtable and subfig modules)

Comment: it would be nice if a syntax example was given for quick reference.

Comment: This is now built in to sphinx.

Comment: The link in the answer is broken. But as @GringoSuave mentioned this is now built into Sphinx. See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36969111/2961550

Answer (score 40):

In the latest versions of Sphinx (1.3+), numbering figures and referencing them from text got a bit easier as support for it is now built-in.

In your text, you can do something like:

```
.. _label:
.. figure:: images/figure.*


At :numref:`label` you can see...
```

The end result should be something like "At Fig 1.1 you can see...". This technique works both with the default HTML output and the LaTeX output.

In your `conf.py` file, make sure to set the flag `numfig = True`. There are also configuration options for the references' text format (`numfig_format` and `numfig_secnum_depth`).

References:

- http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-numfig
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-figures-by-figure-number

Comment: A more recent link: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#cross-referencing-figures-by-figure-number

Comment: Thanks, @wkschwartz - I updated the link on the post.

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the accepted answer, you can quickly get this set up as follows. Put the `numfig.py` file in your `source` directory. Then open `conf.py` and uncomment the line that says

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

Then add `'numfig'` to the `extensions` list.

To use in your `rst` document, first label your figure (e.g., `fig-main`):

```
.. _fig-main:

.. figure:: main.png

   This is the figure caption.
```

Finally, you can reference its figure number using the `:num:` directive, like this:

```
Refer to the main figure (Figure :num:`fig-main`).
```

Comment: This is now built in and the inline role is called: numref 
http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-figures-by-figure-number

Answer (score 0):

I think referencing Figures is not yet implemented in reST, but here is workaround http://article.gmane.org/gmane.text.docutils.user/5623 that gets you closer.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work with Sphinx. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

One can use raw latex code, inline. For the example above, a role for raw latex code is first defined and than used to refer to the figure with the `\ref{}` latex command, and to set a label to the figure with the `\label{}` latex command.

The following should work:

```
.. role:: raw-latex(raw)
     :format: latex

The lemmings are attacking, as can be seen in :ref:`figlem`
on figure :raw-latex:`\ref{pic:lem}`.

.. _figlem:

.. figure:: _static/lemming_invasion.* 

   They're coming! :raw-latex:`\label{pic:lem}`
```

Note that the `\label{}` command will appear inside the caption in the tex file, but it is still acceptable, at least by `pdflatex`. Also note that there should be at least one space before `:raw-latex`.