# csv-table reference as table number rather than table name

Tags: python-sphinx, docutils

I am making a document with many tables.  But, the only way I know how to refer to them in the text is with a `:ref:'my_table'` and that puts the entire table name, "The long title of my table" in my text block.  I would rather have it put in "Table 1.3" instead ... is that possible?

```
.. _my_table:

.. csv-table:: The long title of my table
   :file: my_table.csv
   :header-rows: 1
```

A separate but table related questions: is there a sphinx/docutils option for putting the table name/caption at the bottom rather than the top or is that a stylesheet/latex thing?

Comment: This question is *already* under [your account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/906490/justin). Perhaps you mean a different question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably not a super-easy way to do this, but the [numfig](https://bitbucket.org/arjones6/sphinx-numfig/wiki/Home) extension (as referenced in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686310/referencing-figures-with-numbers-in-sphinx-and-restructuredtext) question) does something very like this for Figures, and could probably be modified/adapted to do something similar for Tables.

A custom extension like this is probably the only way to accomplish this at present.

Comment: How was this done? I looked at how Sphinx converts `csv-table`s to LaTeX and it appears it doesn't create `\label`s to tables and instead uses `\phantomsection`, did you have to override the built in functionality for creating `csv-table`?