# Numbered reference to figures in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

Using sphinx 1.3.6, I cannot find a way to make **numbered references** to figures.

According to answers and comments here: [Referencing figures with numbers in Sphinx and reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686310/referencing-figures-with-numbers-in-sphinx-and-restructuredtext),
`numref` is built into Sphinx.

But this simply does not work:

```
.. _mylabel

.. figure:: img/fig.jpg

   this is the caption
```

When I use `` :numref:`Figure %s <mylabel>` `` in the text, the result is literally `Figure %s` as if `numref` was actually not implemented at all.

Do I need something to put in `conf.py` or in the latex preamble?

Comment: Numbered figures are enabled by setting  `numfig = True` in conf.py. It currently only works for HTML output. See http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-numfig.

Comment: Btw, the label needs a trailing colon: `.. _mylabel:`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing figures with numbers in Sphinx and reStructuredText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686310/referencing-figures-with-numbers-in-sphinx-and-restructuredtext)

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old post, however I thought I'd share what helped me in this case.

The following code will add a numbered link to your image with a numbered title.  For example the link `Fig. 1` will link to the image with the title: **Fig. 1 System Process Flow**

#### documentation.rst File:

```
This is some boring documentation text which refers to the illustration in :numref:`my-image`.

.. figure:: images/process_flow.png
    :name: my-image
    :align: center
    :width: 100%

    System Process Flow
```

#### conf.py File:

Add this line to your `conf.py` file:

```
numfig = True
```

Your Sphinx doc will now have a link to your **numbered figure**.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, page.rst has to be included in some 'toctree'.

Else it will throw errors as follows:

WARNING: no number is assigned for figure: