# How to properly numref table in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am trying to reference a table by its number in a Sphinx doc. I give a name to the table and try to use `numref` afterwards, but it incorrectly displays the table's label ("modules_classes") instead of its number.

```
.. _modules_classes:

.. table:: Modules and their corresponding abstract classes

[table content]

Modules and their corresponding abstract classes are presented on table :numref:`modules_classes`.
```

I've also tried doing like this, as I found an example online, but the outcome is the same:

```
.. table:: Modules and their corresponding abstract classes
    :name: modules_classes
```

The way I see it, I don't need to import the `numfig` package, as it is included in Sphinx by default. Using the command `:ref:` displays the table's caption, so I understand the reference is correct. Can someone point what is wrong in what I've done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The remedy is to set `numfig = True` in conf.py. Without this setting, you should see a message when running **sphinx-build** that says *"WARNING: numfig is disabled. :numref: is ignored"*.

This works for HTML and LaTeX output. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig.

Comment: I just tested it for LaTeX/PDF output. Although the original bug is gone, now I am getting **Table ??** instead of the numbering.

Comment: Oh, and it has worked properly with HTML, just not with LaTeX.

Comment: If you run pdflatex a second time, does the cross-reference to the table get updated?

Comment: It doesn't. I've opened the `tex` file and found `\ref{introduction:modules-classes}` but `\label{index:modules-classes}`. "introduction" is the name of the `.rst` file I'm writing my document, and I don't know where "index" came from.

Comment: I was hoping that you could confirm that `numfig = True` works for LaTeX output too (despite what the Sphinx documentation says). Running latex/pdflatex twice is usually necessary to get references right. I cannot say where "index" came from or whether it is a problem.

Comment: I was using a workaround that compiled the LaTeX and HTML documents in different ways. Since then I've dropped this approach and, with both versions of the document being generated using the same source `rst` files, the table numbering is correct in both.